HTML "required" Attribute does not work for spam bots
I have a form, which users should be able to submit only if they upload/attach a document. For that I use the following line:
<input type="file" id="file" name="attachment" 
       accept=".pdf, .doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" 
       required >

This is the PHP code:
<?php
$postData = $uploadedFile = $statusMsg = '';
$msgClass = 'errordiv';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $postData = $_POST;
    
    $servicetypes = $_POST['servicetypes'];
    $turnaroundspeeds = $_POST['turnaroundspeeds'];
    $englishtype = $_POST['englishtype'];
    $currency = $_POST['currency'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $wordcount = $_POST['wordcount'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $promocode = $_POST['promocode'];
    
    
    
    
    // Check whether submitted data is not empty
    if(!empty($turnaroundspeeds) && !empty($servicetypes) && !empty($englishtype) && !empty($currency) && !empty($email) && !empty($name) ){
        
        // Validate email
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $statusMsg = 'Please enter your valid email.';
        }else{
            $uploadStatus = 1;
            
            // Upload attachment file
            if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){
                
                // File path config
                $targetDir = "uploads/";
                $fileName = basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
                $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
                $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
                

                
                
                
                // Allow certain file formats
                $allowTypes = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
                if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                    // Upload file to the server
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                        $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if($uploadStatus == 1){
                
                // Recipient
                $toEmail = 'submit@example.com';

                // Sender
                $from = 'support@example.com';
                $fromName = 'Customer';
                
                // Subject
                $emailSubject = 'Quote Request Submitted by '.$name;
                
                // Message 
                $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                    <p><b>Service Type:</b> '.$servicetypes.'</p>
                    <p><b>Turnaround Speed:</b> '.$turnaroundspeeds.'</p>
                    <p><b>English Type:</b> '.$englishtype.'</p>
                    <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                    <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                    <p><b>Word Count:</b> '.$wordcount.'</p>
                    <p><b>Promo Code:</b> '.$promocode.'</p>
                    <p><b>Currency:</b> '.$currency.'</p>
                    <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';
                
                // Header for sender info
                $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

                if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile)){
                    
                    // Boundary 
                    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
                    
                    // Headers for attachment 
                    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
                    
                    // Multipart boundary 
                    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 
                    
                    // Preparing attachment
                    if(is_file($uploadedFile)){
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                        $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                        @fclose($fp);
                        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                        "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                    }
                    
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                    $returnpath = "-f" . $email;
                    
                    // Send email
                    $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
                    
                    // Delete attachment file from the server
                    @unlink($uploadedFile);
                }else{
                     // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                    $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                    $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
                    
                 

                    
                    // Send email
                    $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers); 
                }
                
                // If mail sent
                
                if(!$mail) {
  print_r( 'Mailer error: Please send your document through submit@example.com ' . error_get_last());
} else {
  echo 
  header('Location: submit-thank-you.htm');
exit()
}

            }
        }
    }else{
       echo 
  header('Location: problem.htm');
exit();
    }
}
?

This code works for real users: on my webpage, I cannot submit the form without an attachment.
However, I receive many spam submissions without an attachment. How does that even happen? How can I avoid this?
I checked many times, but could not find a solution. Is there anything I can change in the PHP code to prevent spam bots from filling out my form?

Chances are it’s not using a browser, which is why server side validation is always required when it actually matters.

Is there a simple HTML code for server side validation?

Just to get a misunderstanding out of the way: HTML is used in the client to render a web page. HTML code is generated by a server, but it doesn't do anything on the server. This means there is no: "simple HTML code for server side validation". To do anything server side, you need a server side language, for instance, PHP, node.js, python, etc.

You ALWAYS need to validate data sent to a server and receiving side. Any http client can send data to your server.

Is there a simple HTML code for server side validation...not html, no, because that runs in your browser, not on the server. As KIKO says you need a script language to process the form data, you can code the validation  with that. You tagged this post with php so presumably you can use that. A simple script could use isset to check if a form field was completed. You can find examples in a billion places. If you're wanting to guard against bots more generally, consider adding a captcha to your form as well. Again plenty of tutorials cover this

You already have if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]))...but your script doesn't stop or prevent sending the email in the case where it's empty. So just adjust your logic accordingly

Being well behaved is obviously against its interests. Most likely the spambot analyzes your form and then submits data to match its fields.
Client side validation (which includes enforcement of a required rule) is the first thing to go out of the window when dealing with spammers and scammers.

Solution 1 : Implement a Honeypot Field
A honeypot field is a hidden field that should not be filled out by real users but might be filled out by spam bots that automatically submit all form fields. If this field is filled out, you can treat the submission as spam and reject it.
Add a hidden field to your form:
<input type="text" name="honeypot" style="display:none" />

In your backend, check if the honeypot field has been filled out. If it has, reject the form submission.
Solution 2 : Use Google reCAPTCHA
Adding a CAPTCHA like Google reCAPTCHA can significantly reduce the chance of automated submissions. It will ask users to solve a challenge (e.g., identifying objects in images) to prove they're human.

Just in case you did use AI, please see: What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools? The main reason I say this is because your answer doesn't really answer the question, which typically happens when you dump the question in an AI chat bot.

You can add the validation in client side ( js validation ) along with server side validation, with that you can prevent this bot issue and for real user it woks fine. It will add security to your site.

Try this code. $uploadStatus is always true in your code. that's why so many spam without attachment
<?php
$postData = $uploadedFile = $statusMsg = '';
$msgClass = 'errordiv';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $postData = $_POST;
    
    $servicetypes = $_POST['servicetypes'];
    $turnaroundspeeds = $_POST['turnaroundspeeds'];
    $englishtype = $_POST['englishtype'];
    $currency = $_POST['currency'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $wordcount = $_POST['wordcount'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $promocode = $_POST['promocode'];
    
    
    
    
    // Check whether submitted data is not empty
    if(!empty($turnaroundspeeds) && !empty($servicetypes) && !empty($englishtype) && !empty($currency) && !empty($email) && !empty($name) ){
        
        // Validate email
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $statusMsg = 'Please enter your valid email.';
        }else{
            $uploadStatus = 0;
            
            // Upload attachment file
            if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){
                
                // File path config
                $targetDir = "uploads/";
                $fileName = basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
                $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
                $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
                

                
                
                
                // Allow certain file formats
                $allowTypes = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
                if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                    // Upload file to the server
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                        $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                        $uploadStatus = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if($uploadStatus == 1){
                
                // Recipient
                $toEmail = 'submit@example.com';

                // Sender
                $from = 'support@example.com';
                $fromName = 'Customer';
                
                // Subject
                $emailSubject = 'Quote Request Submitted by '.$name;
                
                // Message 
                $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                    <p><b>Service Type:</b> '.$servicetypes.'</p>
                    <p><b>Turnaround Speed:</b> '.$turnaroundspeeds.'</p>
                    <p><b>English Type:</b> '.$englishtype.'</p>
                    <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                    <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                    <p><b>Word Count:</b> '.$wordcount.'</p>
                    <p><b>Promo Code:</b> '.$promocode.'</p>
                    <p><b>Currency:</b> '.$currency.'</p>
                    <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';
                
                // Header for sender info
                $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

                if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile)){
                    
                    // Boundary 
                    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
                    
                    // Headers for attachment 
                    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
                    
                    // Multipart boundary 
                    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 
                    
                    // Preparing attachment
                    if(is_file($uploadedFile)){
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                        $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                        @fclose($fp);
                        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                        "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                    }
                    
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                    $returnpath = "-f" . $email;
                    
                    // Send email
                    $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
                    
                    // Delete attachment file from the server
                    @unlink($uploadedFile);
                }else{
                     // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                    $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                    $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
                    
                 

                    
                    // Send email
                    $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers); 
                }
                
                // If mail sent
                
                if(!$mail) {
  print_r( 'Mailer error: Please send your document through submit@example.com ' . error_get_last());
} else {
  echo 
  header('Location: submit-thank-you.htm');
exit()
}

            }
        }
    }else{
       echo 
  header('Location: problem.htm');
exit();
    }
}
?>

